# why unexpected token: * in when doing operation over two lines

Tags: groovy

Running the following in a 1.8 console:

```
def accessories = null
final int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
result = prime
    * result
        + ((accessories == null) ? 0 : accessories
                .hashCode());
```

I get a compilation error stating:

unexpected token: * at line: 5, column: 13

Yet, when I move "* result" up to the previous line, it compiles and runs cleanly. I've searched to try to find an explanation, but have had no luck thus far. Can someone explain?

```
def accessories = null
final int prime = 31;
int result = 1;
result = prime * result
        + ((accessories == null) ? 0 : accessories
                .hashCode());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Groovy's statements are not delimited by `;`, but rather by line break. It can't know the line below is a continuation of the statement on the line above. You can escape the line break:

```
int i = 10 \
    * 9
assert i == 90
```

---

**Update:**

Actually Groovy does identify some statements as from the above line. At least the dot is recognized:

```
assert [1, 2]
  .join("")
  .padLeft(4, "a") == "aa12"
```

And a statement with either `+`, `-` and `~` (and maybe more) [could be methods](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading):

```
def m = "aa"
  - m // fails with "No signature of method: java.lang.String.negative()"
```

Comment: You just hit the nail on the head. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is necessary because otherwise the parser for Groovy would have to do a lot more work.

There are lots of places ie:

```
String s = "tim"
             + "_yates"
```

Where it would be possible for the parser to work out what you meant, but in all of them, I believe it would involve [backtracking](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/How+to+remove+global+backtracking+from+your+grammar) (or implementing a two pass parse) which is slow

Comment: +1, didn't know about backtracking in parsers... Neither do i know a lot about parsers, also :-)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move the `*` instead of moving `* result` to line 4.

```
result = prime //Line completes with the assignment of prime to result
        * result //Will yield a compilation error
            + ((accessories == null) ? 0 : accessories
                    .hashCode());
```

Instead,

```
result = prime * //Statement expects a RHV (right hand value) for the operator
          result + //Always end the line with an operator
            ((accessories == null) ? 0 : accessories
                    .hashCode());
```

To test the same with `ternary` operator,

```
//Yields to compilation error
def str = "ABC"             
def val = str == "ABC"
? str
: "XYZ"

//Works perfect
def val = str == "ABC" ? 
str : 
"XYZ"
```

Comment: This was not my question. My question is "why is this necessary" not how to resolve it. I had already deduced that. Thanks for the feedback, anyway.

Comment: @BillTurner "Why is it necessary" is mentioned as comments in relevant lines.